# Dynamic Razor Field based on Property Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

I have a model that has several properties on it. I need to generate form fields for each of the properties. The majority of the code is very boiler plate, and I am attempting to make a razor partial or helper that will eliminate the need to retype the logic.

Given the following Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
```

I would like to be able to do something like this, but by passing in the name of the property: `"FirstName"`.

I have created a Razor extension method in order to try and do this:

```
public static class RazorExtensions
{
    public static LambdaExpression GetExpressionForField(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        var propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpression, parameter);

        return exp;
    }
}
```

The usage being:

```
@{
    var expression = RazorExtensions.GetExpressionForField(Model.GetType(), "FirstName");
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(expression)
```

When this executes, I receive a compilation error:

CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

What is the method/process I would need to use in order to be able to explicitly type the expression, or get around this issue?

Comment: Not clear what your trying to do here, or why - there is already a `@Html.DisplayName()` method that accepts a `string` - `@Html.DisplayName("FirstName")`

Comment: `@Html.DisplayName(string)` does not read off of the model and generate attributes for validation (e.g. `data-val-required`).

Comment: Neither does `DisplayNameFor()`! - both generate identical output (i.e. the name of the property, or its value defined by the `[Display]` attribute)

Comment: That's fair. Let me rephrase the question, `DisplayNameFor` is a bad example.

Comment: Then just use `@Html.TextBox("FirstName")`. All the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls have the equivalent (without the `For` suffix) that accept a `string` which is the name of the proeperty

Comment: But why would you not want the strong typed methods anyway?